# WooCommerce: Display ONLY on-sale products in Shop

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, filter, archive

I need to create a **products archive page** (usually the **Shop** page in **WooCommerce**) but displays **ONLY the *ON SALE* products**. Basically it should use the same **template layout** as that in the `archive-product.php`. There will be a link in the main menu that will direct to this page. How do I go about this?

### UPDATE

I managed to filter out the **ON SALE** products with the code below placed just above the `if ( have_posts() ) :` line...

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'paged'          => $paged,
    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key'           => '_sale_price',
            'value'         => 0,
            'compare'       => '>',
            'type'          => 'numeric'
        )
    )
);

query_posts( $args );
```

The code is placed in a **copy** of `archive-product.php` which I named `archive-product_sale.php` and made as a **page template**.

However, this only works for **Simple products** type and I need it to work for both **Simple** products and **Variable** products type.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

@mirus' answer regarding the shortcode gave me the idea to check out how WooCommerce is querying only the on-sale items. Apparently WooCommerce has a `wc_get_product_ids_on_sale()` function that will return the IDs of the on-sale items. Then we can easily adjust the query using the `post__in` parameter to only return those specific items.

WooCommerce has a `woocommerce_product_query` hook in the `class-wc-query.php` class that allows for us to modify the query before it is run.... it is run on `pre_get_posts` which is the usual place for modifying the query.  Using Woo's hook just means you let them handle the majority of the conditional logic about when this query modification should be applied.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'so_20990199_product_query' );

function so_20990199_product_query( $q ){

    $product_ids_on_sale = wc_get_product_ids_on_sale();

    $q->set( 'post__in', $product_ids_on_sale );

}
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. It runs before the main query (better performance), the question seemed to be oriented to the main query (what this method is affecting) and it takes advantage of the work done by Woo.

Comment: Right, this is the correct answer. Meta key '_min_variation_sale_price' doesn't work for me for 'variable products' - I use '$q->set('post__in', (array) $product_ids_on_sale);' 'post__in' is much faster than 'meta_query' and use cache 'transient' and find 'vairiable products' too.

Comment: This worked for me too, somehow some products didn't have "_min_variation_sale_price" meta key

Comment: JEEEZUS .. been looking for this answer for 5 hours. THANK YOU!!
WooCommerce [changed the way they store sale prices](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/10651),  [get_on_sale_products](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/includes/data-stores/class-wc-product-data-store-cpt.php)

Comment: How to order by newest first? Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 11):

I managed to filter out the **ON SALE** products with the code below **placed just above** the `if ( have_posts() ) :` line...

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'meta_query'     => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array( // Simple products type
            'key'           => '_sale_price',
            'value'         => 0,
            'compare'       => '>',
            'type'          => 'numeric'
        ),
        array( // Variable products type
            'key'           => '_min_variation_sale_price',
            'value'         => 0,
            'compare'       => '>',
            'type'          => 'numeric'
        )
    )
);

query_posts( $args );
```

The code is placed in a copy of `archive-product.php` which I renamed `archive-product_sale.php` and made as a **page template**.

Comment: Have you ever come across a problem where the check if sale price is more than 0 meta query returns products *scheduled* to go on sale, but are not currently on sale at the moment? These products should not be returned in the results, but I don't know how to write the meta query to exclude/include scheduled sale products. Cheers

Comment: No, I have never come across such scenario before. Maybe you should create a new question and hopefully someone would be able to help. I'm sure alot of us would like to find out too.

Comment: How to make it work with built-in woocommerce filters? I have already page template displaying all products on sale, but I would like to filter by category, price, etc. (using default woocommerce)? When I change category now, ALL products are shown (not only with sale badge).

Comment: I would assume adding the category to the argument would be a start. Try creating a new question, though, that is specific to your case. It might come in handy for many of us.

Comment: Dont forget to add `'paged'  => $paged,` as @Giraldi has added in his edit. Otherwise the pagination will not work!

Answer (score 6):

[@gmaggio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/851045/gmaggio) using query_posts() [will break your site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts).
Use [pre_get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'catalog_filters' );
function catalog_filters( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && $query->post_type = 'product' ) {
        if(isset($_GET['onsale'])) {
            $meta_query = array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array( // Simple products type
                'key' => '_sale_price',
                'value' => 0,
                'compare' => '>',
                'type' => 'numeric'
                ),
                array( // Variable products type
                'key' => '_min_variation_sale_price',
                'value' => 0,
                'compare' => '>',
                'type' => 'numeric'
                )
            ); $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
        }
        if(isset($_GET['bestsellers'])) {
            $meta_query     = array(
            array( 
                'key'           => 'total_sales',
                'value'         => 0,
                'compare'       => '>',
                'type'          => 'numeric'
                )
            );
        }
    }

return $query;
}
```

Comment: Cheers! I'll try it out when I have the time to look back on that project. Tx for the info! :)

Comment: This works. However applying additional filters on the archive page overwrites it, because it's not behaving as an "AND" filter like the standard does.

Comment: @Skovsgaard I dont have WP to test

Answer (score 2):

Create a new page using shortcode `[sale_products per_page="12"]`

List of available shortcodes and their parameters is here: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/

Comment: He only wants to show items on sale. This will still keep the original shop page... and items that are not on sale

Comment: oh, i see now what do you mean

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I am aware of this **shortcode** but I needed it to be in the same **template layout** as that of the `archive-product.php` complete with the result count, sorting filter, pagination, etc.

Comment: @gmaggio, sorry, had a bit misunderstandings regards your question

Answer (score 0):

Solution for variable and simple products:

```
add_action( 'save_post_product', 'update_product_set_sale_cat_var' );

function update_product_set_sale_cat_var( $post_id ) {

    $sales_ids = wc_get_product_ids_on_sale();

    foreach ( $sales_ids as $sale_id ) :
        if ($sale_id == $post_id) :
            wp_set_object_terms($post_id, 'sale', 'product_cat', true );
        else :
            if ( has_term( 'sale', 'product_cat', $post_id ) ) {
                wp_remove_object_terms( $post_id, 'sale', 'product_cat' );
            }
        endif;
    endforeach; 

}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: For some reason I can't get this to work. The category is created if it doesn't exist, but the product is not assigned to it. The category remains empty without any associated products, even if I try to save again.

Answer (score 0):

@butiri-dan, your solution when we save/update a product to change the category sale is interresting but unfortunately "wrong" because the product is not yet in (or out) in sale when 'save_post_product' is triggered so `wc_get_product_ids_on_sale()` do not containt the current product id yet if we add a sale price at the first time. Finaly, your function works only at the second time we save the product and only if the product on sale value do not change.

My participation can be help (maybe). In my case this code works like a charm :

```php
add_action('woocommerce_update_product', 'update_product_set_sale_cat_var');
add_action('woocommerce_new_product', 'update_product_set_sale_cat_var');

function update_product_set_sale_cat_var( $post_id ) {
    $saleCategorySlug = 'promos';
    $product = wc_get_product($post_id);
    if ($product->get_sale_price() === $product->get_price() && !has_term( $saleCategorySlug, 'product_cat', $post_id ) ) {
        wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $saleCategorySlug, 'product_cat', true );
    }
    else if($product->get_sale_price() !== $product->get_price() && has_term( $saleCategorySlug, 'product_cat', $post_id )){
        wp_remove_object_terms( $post_id, $saleCategorySlug, 'product_cat' );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading all the options, it seems I came to the simplest solution for myself and it seems to work

```
$args => array(
    'type' => array( 'simple', 'variation' ) ,
    'include' =>  wc_get_product_ids_on_sale(), // only products from this array
)

$products = wc_get_products($args);
```

`'type' => 'variation'` If you need to display each variation as a separate product card

`'type' => 'variable'` If you need a parent variation object with a button, select options instead of adding to cart

For some reason I didn’t find anything about `variation` in the documentation [wc_get_products()](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query)

I'm not a Woocommerce specialist, I'm only doing my second project on it. And at almost every stage I encounter difficulties. And in general, I'm more of a frontend developer.
I literally just wrote the solution, at first glance it works as expected and I hope it will continue to do so.

Sorry if this code is incorrect.
And sorry for my English, this is Google translator).
I hope this helps at least someone