# Woocommerce - Showing only products in stock

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

a client want to show a total of the amount of products they have in their shop, I have used this code

```
$numposts = (int) $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'product' AND post_status = 'publish'");
```

Which works fine, however it shows the total number of published products and I want it to only show where stock is at 1 or greater, so basically it only shows the total number of products that are in actually in stock

Comment: To count all in stocks product you must have to join other table `wp_postmeta` with field `_sale_price` which is greator than `0`

Comment: Sorry you will need to talk to me like a child, how do I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20990199/woocommerce-display-only-on-sale-products-in-shop

Comment: Try this `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts p INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta pm ON p.id = pm.post_id WHERE p.post_type = 'product' AND p.post_status = 'publish' AND pm.meta_key = "_sale_price" AND pm.meta_value > 0`

Comment: No that failed, it referred to _sale_price as the error, I am not sure this is right, I don't want anything to do with sale price I want any product with a stock quantity of 1 or more not sale price

Comment: That returns anything with a sale price over $0, not everything that is in stock. Depending on what type of inventory you use, probably better to use the `_stock` or `_stock_status` meta values, see below.

Comment: FWIW the issue with the value in the query above is that "_sale_price" is using double quotes when it should be using single as in '_sale_price'. That said it still won't return the info you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try joining to the post_meta table using the `_stock_status` meta_key where the meta_value is 'instock'. Caching the data is recommended since you don't want to run this on every request but will need to balance an appropriate amount of time to cache the data (since sales within the cache period won't be reflected in the total number of instock items). Only works if you are using a cache (which is highly recommended with WooCommerce due to the number of queries).

```
global $wpdb;
// cache key
$key = 'in_stock_products';
// we get back 'false' if there is nothing in the cache, otherwise 0+
$in_stock_products = wp_cache_get( $key );
// run the query if we didn't get it from the cache
if ( false === $in_stock_products ){
    // create the SQL query (HEREDOC format)
    $sql_query = <<<SQL
    SELECT COUNT(p.ID) AS in_stock_products
    FROM {$wpdb->posts} p
    JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} pm 
        ON p.ID = pm.post_id 
        AND pm.meta_key = '_stock_status' 
        AND pm.meta_value = 'instock'
    WHERE p.post_type = 'product' AND p.post_status = 'publish'
SQL;
    // query the database
    $in_stock_products = (int) $wpdb->get_var( $sql_query );
    // cache the results, choosing an appropriate amount of time to cache results
    $cache_ttl = 0; // 0 is "as long as possible", otherwise cache time in seconds
    wp_cache_add( $key, $in_stock_products, $cache_ttl ); // cache as long as possible
}
// $in_stock_products now has the value either from the cache or the database query.
echo "There are $in_stock_products in stock";
```

Comment: Great! I would recommend using `wp_cache_get()` and `wp_cache_add()` for this value as well so you don't run the SQL query on every request.

Comment: Sorry forgive my ignorance but how do you do this??