# Get the count of all "In stock" products in WooCommerce

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I have a site where products are considered trade/deal.  Therefore, when someone take a trade (buy a product), it become out of stock.

What would be the PHP snippet to display the remaining numbers of product currently available (basically In Stock) ?

ex: Hurry Up! Only 10 trades (woocommerce -> products) available!

Thanks in advance!

I tried the code provided :

```
function fp2() {
    global $wpdb; 

    $stock = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_stock', true ); 

    echo '<span style="color:#fff;text-align:center;font-size:12px">Remaining Trade:' . $stock;
}
add_shortcode('fp7', 'fp2');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Woocommerce - Showing only products in stock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412782/woocommerce-showing-only-products-in-stock)

Comment: I would suggest to look at accepted answer for linked duplicate question above as it 'caches' the result otherwise you would run an expensive SQL query on every page load where this function is called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updated *(2021)*

Here is a custom function with a SQL query that will return the products "instock" count:

```
function get_instock_products_count(){
    global $wpdb;

    // The SQL query
    $result = $wpdb->get_var( "
        SELECT COUNT(p.ID)
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        WHERE p.post_type LIKE '%product%'
        AND p.post_status = 'publish'
        AND pm.meta_key = '_stock_status'
        AND pm.meta_value = 'instock'
    " );
    
    return reset($result);
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and working

---

**Usage example** *(in any php file)*:

```
$count = get_instock_products_count();
$message = sprintf( __( 'Hurry Up! Only %s remaining trades' ), $count );
echo '<div class="woocommerce-message">'.$message.'</div>';
```

will display something like:

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!  Not sure If I can ask another question here (new to this platform) but here it is in case or let me know if I should post a fresh question on this site....   Same basis.. is there a way to display the number of products that has been published today  (new)

Comment: Hi again, sorry about this, im pretty new on this site, i clicked on your solution now.  Agreed with your solution more.  Thank you, apologize

Comment: @enkiki I have maid an answer then… you can check it if ou like.

Comment: Thank you very much Loic, awesome!  I created another question which combine both of your solution in one but no luck,,, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47809990/woocommerce-combine-3-php-functions-in-one   Feel free to take a look :)

Comment: Hi LoicTheAztec, if you have time to read my new question that would be awesome and very very appreciated... I'm basically just waiting for the right solution and move forward! Even willing to pay you tip !! :)

Comment: Salut Loic, c'etait plutot la question " https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47809990/woocommerce-combine-3-php-functions-in-one " .. combine vos deux scripts ensemble.  Merci de votre cousine Quebecoise :)

Comment: HP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: reset()