# WooCommerce: Display ONLY discounted product in list

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

From this question
[WooCommerce: Display ONLY on-sale products in Shop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20990199/woocommerce-display-only-on-sale-products-in-shop) I tried to display product those are discounted. But every time it's displaying all products those are `on_sale` .
I also tried `_sale_price` meta key. But can't understand how can I solve my problem. 
My project output from my code
[image]

My `$args` variable

```
$args = array(
'post_type'      => 'product',
'order'          => 'ASC',
'meta_query'     => array(
    array(
        'key'           => '_sale_price',
        'value'         => 0,
        'compare'       => '>',
        'type'          => 'numeric'
    )
)
);
```

I also tried below code. But same result

```
$args = array(
'post_type'      => 'product',
'posts_per_page' => 8,
'meta_query'     => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array( // Simple products type
        'key'           => '_sale_price',
        'value'         => 0,
        'compare'       => '>',
        'type'          => 'numeric'
    ),
    array( // Variable products type
        'key'           => '_min_variation_sale_price',
        'value'         => 0,
        'compare'       => '>',
        'type'          => 'numeric'
    )
)
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some how I solved my problem. I was wrong when I posted product from admin panel. My code was right. When I posted Product I set price on sale price instead of regular price. Now I removed product sale price those are not discounted. And place that price on regular price. Now My problem solved. This is my output.
[image]

My work in admin panel

[image]